# Getting symlink path in original case in bash on case insensitive file system on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, symlink

Folder structure

```
/Users/alex/projects/Demo
/Users/alex/projects/Demo/test  ->  ../Demo2
/Users/alex/projects/Demo2
```

`test` is a symlink to `../Demo2`.

The issue is that on case-insensitive fs I can do:

```
cd /Users/alex/projects/dEmo/tEst
```

And it will work. `pwd` will show this `..dEmo/tEst` instead or the original case.

I need to get the path in the original case and *not* resolve link while doing it.

I.e. I need to get `/Users/alex/projects/Demo/test` even if user `cd`-ed into `/Users/alex/projects/dEmo/tEst`.

If not for symlink I would have just used `realpath $(pwd)`. But it resolves symlinks. `realpath` has an `-s` switch but in that case it just does nothing leaving the input as is and returns the incorrect `/Users/alex/projects/dEmo/tEst`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about this, but how about using `stat`? In Linux, `stat -c %n path/to/file` will give you the filename

Comment: stat on macos does not have `-c` option but I assusme it's a format and you meant to print file name from stat output. Unfortunately if I cd-ed into a "camlecased" dir, then `stat $(pwd)` will return it's name as is `/Users/alex/projects/dEmo/tEst`.

Comment: Looks like I will have to create a function to iterate over path and find canonical name for each part...

Comment: None of the usual commands return the normalized name as it is written in the node? `ls`, `find`, etc? Oh man :(

Comment: Oh they do but how would I use them to achieve the result?

Comment: you could write a fairly simple script that walks up the directory tree, and uses `ls` to get the proper case as it goes.

Comment: Yes I could but maybe there's a better way? Just don't want to reinvent a wheel without a need.

Comment: With bash 4.2.8: `shopt -s nocaseglob; cd /Users/alex/projects/*dEmo/*tEst; pwd`?

Comment: So, I'll bite. Why do you "need to get the path in the original case"? What are you going to use it for or do with it? There may be a better approach.

Comment: I run a daemon that uses current path as a parameter and I need to limit it to have only 1 instance per path. I do this by comparing current path with running instances paths to avoid running duplicate damon-path instances. 
Doing a case-insensitive comparison is not an option, because it's a cross-platform script which is supposed to work with case-sensitive filesystems as well.
I could detect if FS is case-insensitive and do a insensitive comparison but that is a big effort changing 4k+ lines script. Smaller effort would be for me to figure a way to get canonical path of a dir.

Comment: @Cyrus macOS has bash 3.x